# Calculating CAN bus speed

Tags: c

I need to validate and characterize CAN bus traffic for our product (call it the Unit Under Test, UUT).  I have a machine that sends a specified number of can frames to our product.  Our product is running a Linux based custom kernel. The CAN frames are pre-built in software on the sender machine using a specific algorithm.  The UUT uses the algorithm to verify the received frames.
Also, and here is where my questions lie, I am trying to calculate some timing data in the UUT software.  So I basically do a read loop as fast as possible.  I have a pre-allocated buffer to store the frames, so I just call read and increment the pointer to the buffer:

```
    clock_gettime(clocK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,  timespec_start_ptr);
    while ((frames_left--) > 0)
        read(can_sock_fd, frame_mem_ptr++, sizeof(struct can_frame));  

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,  timespec_stop_ptr);
```

My question has to do with the times I get when I calculate the difference in these two timespecs (the calculation I use is correct I have verified it, it is GNUs algorithm).
Also, running the program under the time utility agrees with my times.  For example, my program is called tcan, so I might run
[prompt]$ time ./tcan can1 -nf 10000

to run on can1 socket with 10000 frames.  (This is FlexCAN, socket based interface, BTW)

Then, I use the time difference to calculate the data transfer speed I obtained.  I received num_frames in the time span, so I calculate the frames/sec and the bits/sec

I am getting bus speeds that are 10 times the CAN bus speed of 250000 bits per sec.  How can this be?  I only get 2.5% CPU utilization according to both my program and the time program (and the top utility as well).
Are the values I am calculating meaningful?  Is there something better I could do?  I am assuming that since time reports real times that are much greater than user+sys, there must be some time-accounting lost somewhere. Another possibility is that maybe it's correct, I don't know, it's puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a long shot, but what if read() is returning early because otherwise it would have to wait for incoming data? The fastest data to read is none at all :)

It would mess up the timings, but have you tried doing this loop whilst error checking? Or implement the loop via a recv() which should block unless you have asked it not to?

Hopefully this helps.